# Filling Progress Bar with text entered in TextField in java

Tags: java

How to fill up progress bar by entering the text in textfield. The progress bar should increment double when user enter numbers or special characters. The aim is to set up the strength of password field.

Comment: Swing, JavaFX, or something else?

Comment: Did you try this in yourself?

Comment: Swing package..

Comment: Yes i tried too many times..

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DocumentListener`. An event will be generated whenever text is added or removed from the text field.

So then you just need to get the current text and check the entire string for your special characters and reset the value of your progress bar.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listening For Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and working examples.

The tutorial also contains a section on `How to Use Progress Bars`.